# Whitespace at the end of line is not ignored by python regex

Tags: python, regex

The leading spaces are ignored but the trailing ones are not in the below regular expression code. It's just a `"Name = Value"` string but with spaces. I thought the `\s*` after the capture would ignore spaces.

```
import re
line = "  Name =  Peppa Pig  "
match = re.search(r"\s*(Name)\s*=\s*(.+)\s*", line)
print(match.groups())
>>>('Name', 'Peppa Pig   ')  # Why extra spaces after Pig!
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Regardless the question, you can use `match = match.strip()` to delete the leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: See my explanation of what is going on, and a [regex+strip based solution below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39154879/3832970).

Comment: @OhadEytan - Yes I can of course strip in python but I wanted to understand the regex way because the line may have more that one "name = value" pairs. i.e. there could be more captures on the line

Comment: Understandable, that's why I open with _"Regardless the question"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `(.+)\s*` *(where the `\s*` is useless since "zero or more white-spaces" isn't a constraint after the greedy quantifier `.+`, it's like to write nothing)*, you can use `(.*\S)` that will trim automatically the string after the last non-whitespace character `\S`.

```
match = re.search(r"\b(Name)\s*=\s*(.*\S)", line)
```

Question: is the capture of the already known "Name" literal string really needed?

Answer (score 8):

You're getting trailing spaces because of greedy nature of `.+`.

You can use this regex to correctly capture your value:

```
>>> re.search(r"\s*(Name)\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*$", line).groups()
('Name', 'Peppa Pig')
```

`\s*$` ensures we are capturing value before trailing white spaces at end.

Comment: As an outsider who may have had a question like this at some point.. what does the added `?` do in `(.+?)`?

Comment: `.+?` makes it a lazy match as against the greedy `.+`

Comment: But lazy quantifier loses in performance to greedy one (see Casimir's answer) uness there are a lot of spaces at the end.

Comment: Also, let regex do its hard work, and let Python do the trimming work. Take the best from both worlds :)

Comment: @anubhava - Nice but I liked Casimir's answer better

Comment: Yes indeed even I like his regex as it is shorter and faster.

Answer (score 3):

The last `.+` grabs the whole rest of the line (as `.` matches any char but a newline), and then starts backtracking, checking if the subsequent subpatterns should match. Since the subsequent subpattern is `\s*` that can match an empty string (it matches 0+ whitespaces), this pattern successfully matches at the end of the string, and a valid match with trailing whitespaces is returned.

See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dL6eN0/1) (pay special attention at Step 15):

[image]

You may let Python do the `strip` job inside a list comprehension and simplify the regex to just `(Name)\s*=(.+)`:

```
import re
line = "  Name =  Peppa Pig  "
match = [(x,y.strip()) for x,y in re.findall(r"(Name)\s*=(.+)", line)]
print(match)
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/OSXzdM)